# How does the M-law Synchronizer work?

Tags: phase, synchronization

Relatively new to DSP, I've came across the approach for phase-estimation of PSK-Signals x(k): [image]

My question is:

- What do we get by exponentiating the Baseband-Signal?

Comment: Usually, the books that introduce the M-law synchronizers also have an explanation right next to it! The answer is simple: write your M-PSK symbols in amplitude/phase form (i.e. $x = |x| \cdot e^{j\angle x}$) and exponentiate by M, and don't forget about the $2\pi$-periodicity of $e^{jt}$. Question answered!

Comment: Ah, OK so the symbols |x| are becoming "1" by exponating with M?

Comment: :) you've got it! And: what will you do if you get something that is not exactly +1 or -1?

Comment: (by the way, I'm counting on you writing your own answer to your own question if you solve this :) I could write an answer, but I'll be honest: It'd be the same perspective that everyone has who's read the same textbook as me, and thus a bit redundant to similar answers. Your perspective and wording would be valueable!)

Comment: when the symbols are not exactly +1 and -1, then we have to accumulate over a long stream? dividing by M is normalizing the phase...

Comment: sounds about right – the phase of whatever you get will be 8× the absolute value of your phase offset

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Do you mean $M$ times the absolute value of your phase offset?

Comment: err, yes, I guess. Don't know where the 8 came from. At the moment, not even sure where the absolute comes from – we're in the complex plane, this is unambiguous. ${e^{j\frac{2pi}M m + \varphi}}^M = {e^{jM\frac{2pi}M m + M\varphi}} = e^{j2\pi m}\cdot e^{jM\varphi} = 1\cdot e^{jM\varphi}$, sounds about right.